# SQL Query performance: multiple column

Tags: mysql, sql

Its may be a very poor inquiry.

For example I have this table

```
`TABLE1(pkid, fk1_tbl2, someid1_tbl2, someid2_tbl2, col5, col6)`

`TABLE2(pkid, someid1, someid2, col4_2, col5_2, col6_2)`
```

Which means columns `pkid, fk1_tbl2` are indexed

Question 1:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE pkid = 'SOMEID'

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE pkid = 'SOMEID' AND col5 = 'SOME_THING'
```

Assuming that, these two will return same set of data.

Then which one should be faster?

Question 2:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.fk1_tbl2=T2.PKID WHERE T1.pkid = 'SOMEID'
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 T1 JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T1.fk1_tbl2=T2.PKID AND T1.someid1_tbl2= T2.someid1 WHERE T1.pkid = 'SOMEID'
```

Assuming that, these two will return same set of data. Then which one should be faster?

Comment: The EXPLAIN should tell you what you want to know

Comment: You have asked two questions.  That is one question too many for Stack Overflow.